# Why isn't the text hyphenated?

Tags: babel

I can't resolve this. The text "definizione," doesn't get hyphenated. This is an Italian text and I used `babel` italian package but it doesn't fix that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[default]{cantarell}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian, english]{babel}


\begin{document}

Un \textbf{Sistema Informativo} è il complesso di competenze e risorse umane, di macchine ed impianti, di procedure organizzato, strutturato e dedicato alla definizione, manutenzione ed evoluzione della BI.
\end{document}
```

[image: testo]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default language used by `babel` is the last one being declared. You should swap `english` and `italian`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %%  <--- not strictly necessary since 2018
\usepackage[default]{cantarell}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}

\begin{document}

Un \textbf{Sistema Informativo} è il complesso di competenze e risorse umane,
di macchine ed impianti, di procedure organizzato, strutturato e dedicato
alla definizione, manutenzione ed evoluzione della BI.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. You resolved my problem!